# Is there any possibility to use the Brother VC-500W from self coded applications?

Tags: python, java, printing, brother-print-sdk

I've a Brother VC-500W, and it seems to me, that there is no possibility to use it in external applications. For other models there is the b-pac sdk, but I haven't found anything similar for the VC-500W.
Does anybody here have some tips or a solution how I can use it in my applications, e.g. in python, java or any other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's been a while since this question was asked, the answer is yes! Some amazing person has reverse engineered the protocol and has provided a python module and a shell script to print from the printer. They've made the code availible here: https://m7i.org/projects/labelprinter-linux-python-for-vc-500w/ ([Archive.org version)](https://web.archive.org/web/20240106061259/https://m7i.org/projects/labelprinter-linux-python-for-vc-500w/)
as well as a blog post explaining their reverse engineering process.

Someone has also forked the package and fixed some bugs (specifically one that caused the printer to lock up when printing a non jpeg) which is availible here: https://gitlab.com/lenchan139/labelprinter-vc500w ([Archive.org version](https://web.archive.org/web/20240106061648/https://gitlab.com/lenchan139/labelprinter-vc500w))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).